# oracle sql break out records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table that has a StartDate and EndDate field, and also a ton of other fields. I need to break out each record by all the days between and including StartDate & EndDate into another table that looks exactly like the original except it has a CurrentDate field and 2 calculated fields. The CurrentDate field is the current date between StartDate and EndDate that I'm interating on.

My question is, since there are a ton of fields in this, is there any easy way from within my stored proc, to insert the entire row the cursor is currently on AND this 1 new column, without having to list out every single row in the insert statement? It's so tedious.

Comment: Are you trying to write a query that returns multiple copies of the row with a different `CurrentDate`?  Are you trying to write code that inserts the data into another table?  Something else?  You talk about a cursor but then you're also talking about an `INSERT` statement.  Do you need this to be PL/SQL because you're doing a bunch of additional manipulations?  Or would a single SQL statement work since that would be more efficient?

Comment: A single sql statement would be nice but I'm not sure it's possible to "make" more multiple records from 1 record using 2 fields in the 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

If your source and destination tables fit this profile:

1. Destination table columns are the same as your source table's columns, and
2. The new destination column is at the end

... then you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT Source_Table.*, new_value
  FROM Source_Table
  WHERE Source_Table.PKValue = cursor.PKValue
```

If it's a case of your cursor resembling the destination table, something like this *may* work but note I haven't tested it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE whatever IS
  destRow dest_table%ROWTYPE;
  CURSOR fromSourceTable IS
    SELECT <your existing select list>, NULL AS new_value
    FROM <the rest of your cursor query>;
BEGIN
  FOR destRow IN fromSourceTable LOOP
     destRow.new_value = <the split date>;
     INSERT INTO dest_table VALUES destRow;
  END LOOP;
END whatever;
```

I'm going out on a limb with the `NULL AS new_value`. If you have trouble try `CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS new_value` instead, and if you still have trouble try something like `SYSDATE AS new_value`. Again, this isn't tested but if you think it's promising and have trouble implementing I'd be happy to test it.

Comment: So your second part would work, but I have 1 extra column in the destination table which is the date that's being split out.

Comment: I may be able to get a little closer here; I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: I should stop saying "a moment" and just say "a few minutes" :) At any rate, the answer is updated. Let me know if this is close; this is an interesting question and I'd be happy to test here at home but only if you think this approach has promise.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to densify the data in a single SQL statement.  Assuming that you know a reasonable minimum and maximum range for your `begin_date` and `end_date` (I'll assume Jan 1, 2000 - Dec 31, 2020 for the moment but you can obviously adjust that)

```
WITH all_days AS (
  SELECT date '2000-01-01' + level dt
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= date '2020-12-31' - date '2000-01-01'
)
SELECT <<list of colums from your table>>,
       all_days.dt current_date
  FROM your_table actual
       JOIN all_days ON (actual.begin_date <= all_days.dt AND
                         actual.end_date   >= all_days.dt)
```

If you don't want to hard-code the starting and ending dates, you can fetch them from your table as well.  That just requires that you hit the table a second time which will generally be less efficient.